# Add media with WP-Rest-API v2

Tags: media, rest-api

I need your help to upload a media image in my wordpress blog via the Wp-rest-api v2 and Oauth2 authentication.

I did not find in the REST API documentation the way to send my image data (name of field, sending mode...?).

```
require('OAuth2/Client.php');
require('OAuth2/GrantType/IGrantType.php');
require('OAuth2/GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php');

const CLIENT_ID     = 'XXX';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'XX';

const REDIRECT_URI           = 'http://127.0.0.1/test_api_wp/test.php';

const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'http://wordpress.local/oauth/authorize';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'http://wordpress.local/oauth/token';

$client = new OAuth2\Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

if (!isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $auth_url = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, REDIRECT_URI);
    header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
    die('Redirect');
}
else
{
    $params = array('code' => $_GET['code'], 'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI);
    $response = $client->getAccessToken(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code', $params); //authorization_code
    $token = $response['result']['access_token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
    $client->setAccessTokenType(OAuth2\Client::ACCESS_TOKEN_BEARER);

}

$values = array(
    "date" => "2015-11-26 10:00:00",
    "date_gmt" => "2015-11-26 09:00:00",
    "modified" => "2015-11-26 10:00:00",
    "modified_gmt" => "2015-11-26 09:00:00",
    "status" => "future",
    "title" => "Titre media",       
    "description" => "description media",
    "media_type" => "image",
    "source_url" => "https://www.base64-image.de/build/img/mr-base64-482fa1f767.png"
);

$data = $client->fetch("wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/media", $values, "POST");
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";
```

The response :

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [code] => rest_upload_no_data
            [message] => No data supplied
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [status] => 400
                )

        )

    [code] => 400
    [content_type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
)
```

Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I've added the coded from your comment to the question. Remember that you can edit the question at any time to add more information or make it more clear.

Comment: The extra `;` in `wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/media";`is a mistype here or it is in your real code too?

Comment: According with [docs](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1), WP REST API v2 requires [this OAuth plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1). I don't know if the library that you are using (OAuth2/Client.php) is compatible with WP REST API or not, but it is probably not.

Comment: Thanks a lot !The extra --> ; is not present in my real code! I use official OAuth plugin to authenticate me, files OAuth2.Client.php is only library to make curl requests easily

Comment: There is a Create a Media section in (documentation)[http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/media/]. I think your `source_url` should be inside `post` object.

Comment: Hello ville6000, can you explain your comment ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SO! This is fun.

Keep in mind the WP-API is still very, very much a work-in-progress.

### Content-Disposition

I found [an issue reported on the WP-API issue queue](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1744) about Content-Disposition. This is a required header for posting new media content and there are some very, very strict requirements when it comes to providing this in the proper format.

### The Purpose of Create Media Endpoint

First, Let's take a step back. The API assumes at this point you have already uploaded a new file to the correct directory. This endpoint is creating the media content in the database that references this file.

### The solution

You have to specify the filename of the media file to associate to your new content. This cannot be a remote url. As you can see from the [v2 documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/media/), `source_url` and `link` are read-only. All you have to do to successfully submit your new content is add the following to your header:

```
'Content-Disposition' => 'filename=name-of-file.jpg',
```

As mentioned in the ticket, you cannot add quotes or specify the method you're using to send the file. It **must** be in the format above. At least, this is the case until they change it all around.

Make sure the file type is one of the [accepted file types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files) and you're including the extension of the file is included in the request. Thanks to [Dr Deo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9335/dr-deo) in the comments.

For the record, I laughed with giddy joy when I finally figured this one out... scared the hell out of my wife.

Comment: Big thx for the hint with the `Content-Disposition` !

Comment: I think this answer is only a hint, and not a complete solution. I am following this advice and i obtain the error `Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons`

Comment: @Brethlosze That sounds like an unrelated issue. WordPress blocks certain types of media in the normal upload process.

Comment: @Brethlosze the file extension needs to be one of the accepted types. For example this works `curl --request POST --url http://localhost/kayinjaproject/wp-json/wp/v2/media --header "cache-control: no-cache" --header "content-disposition: attachment; filename=tmp.png" --header "authorization: Basic cm9vdDppYW1haGVybw==" --header "content-type: image/png" --data-binary "@c:/gnu/png.png" --location` but if you omit the `png` from the filename `tmp.png`, you get `error sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons`

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of "cross-referencing", see my [related answer here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103707/wp-rest-api-how-to-upload-featured-image/38469742#38469742) about media upload and using that media as "featured media" for a post.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for PHP CURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'EndPoint',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE('LocalFilePathHere')),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.jpg',
    'Content-Type: image/jpeg',
    'Authorization: XXX YYY'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

If you still face issue "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons", you have to add to wp-config.php to disable Fiter for Admin User

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```