# Passing PHP Function Arguments from CLI vs URL

Tags: php

For this code:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');

if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
  $post_id          =$argv[1]; 
  $post_title       =$argv[2];
}
else {
  $post_id          =$_GET['post_id']; 
  $post_title       =$_GET['post_title']; 
}
if (empty($_GET)){
  $post_id = 0;
  $post_title='My Post Title';
}

echo "Done";
return;
```

This call throws no errors, warning or notices, and shows the message `Done`.

```
https://www.example.com/function.php?post_id=0&post_title=My Post Title
```

This call

```
php -f ~/public_html/function.php -- 0 'My Post Title'
```

throws the following warning and notice, and do not show the message `Done`:

```
Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_PROTOCOL in /home/examplecom/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 16
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/examplecom/public_html/wp-includes/load.php:16) in /home/examplecom/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1223
```

How should I fix that?

Comment: Besides i am getting the error `include_once:322 mocd: !is_admin(), or doing cron -- exiting` for both calls...

Comment: Have you considered using WP CLI commands instead? It's a lot easier than rolling your own from scratch

Comment: how to write a WP CLI command: https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/commands-cookbook/ there's no need to bootstrap your own scripts when all the problems have already been solved by an official tool

Comment: The WP CLI looks very promising. But at this point, I still need PHP for running some very simple operations (search post by slug) which WP CLI do not have implemented. Somebody wrote a plugin for fixing that. Some part is solved in the WP REST API, and the other part is solved in the WP CLI. Then i should mix both these inside... PHP. Not so promising though.

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes... All this week [i've been trying](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325776/add-media-with-wp-rest-api-v2-ii) to make the WP REST API work, and yesterday the WP CLI, and both of them simply do not get the job done. WP REST API do not upload and attach media files and thumbnails, and WP CLI cannot find by slug. Hence i just made my own PHP code and it just works.

Comment: But you **can** search for posts via a slug. If you couldn't though, just copy paste the command from the cookbook. Afterall if this is something you're actually going to use, why do it this way then have all these problems? WP CLI solves them and a tonne you're unaware of. Also that comment is the first time you've mentioned the rest api. Are you sure this couldn't be solved with some basic programming common sense where you put your code inside a function that returns data? Why conflate the two with a weird script? Especially since it has issues

Comment: Just because you can't upload via the standard API endpoint doesn't mean you can't just write your own endpoint. As for WP CLI, you never asked if it was possible, but even if a command didn't come out of the box, you could have added one. The REST API and WP CLI are extensible

Comment: Actually this is an open ticket [Get Post By Slug](https://github.com/wp-cli/entity-command/issues/226). The command `wp post list --post_name=<name> --fields=post_title` just throw all the posts.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't write your own WP CLI command, wether the subcommands that come out of the box can do it is irrelevant, I'm telling you that you can add your own, and that's the answer

Comment: Also, that open issue is user error, use `--name` instead of `--post_name` and it works

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```php
function foo_command( $args ) {
    WP_CLI::success( $args[0] );
}
WP_CLI::add_command( 'foo', 'foo_command' );
```

And put it in a plugin, then run:

`wp foo "hello world"`

And it will print out hello world.

Just because the built in subcommands don't do what you need them to do, doesn't mean you can't add your own. WP CLI will take care of bootstrapping WordPress and loading things properly ( and it avoids the security issues of standalone endpoint PHP files such as the one in your question )

However, I suspect the solution to your actual problem is this:

```
wp post list --name="hello-world" --fields="id"
```

And for the REST API:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/slug?="hello-world"
```

Comment: +1 The [WP CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/) `wp post list` documentation declares a `post_name` field... I don't know why the `name` field is used in here instead. But with this modification the GitHub [Get Post By Slug](https://github.com/wp-cli/entity-command/issues/226) ticket has a solution.